# Entity Framework 5 Fluent API - Configure Unidirectional Relationship

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I can't for the life of me figure this out. The articles on MSDN are not clear and seem out of date. I am using EF 5 and I am trying to set up a unidirectional relationship for the following. So here is what I have so far.

```
public sealed class Capture {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Capture's Unique Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Capture's Operating System.
    /// </summary>
    public OperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; set; }
}

public sealed class OperatingSystem {
    /// <summary>
    /// Operating System's Unique Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class EntityCaptureConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Capture> {
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an Entity Capture Configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public EntityCaptureConfiguration() {
        this.ToTable("Capture");
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        this.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        this.HasRequired(m => m.OperatingSystem).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => {
            m.ToTable("OperatingSystem");
            m.MapKey("OperatingSystemId");
        });
    }
}
```

Compile and run and I get the following runtime exception: "*error 3034: Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 16, 46:Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns.*"

I can't help but notice that there is literally no clear way to indicate that I want to join these 2 tables using 2 specific keys. I mean where the heck do I specify the key in the child table to use for a join in the parent table?

Here is what I need help with:

1. I don't want to expose a property on the **Capture** type named
   "*OperatingSystemId*". The "*OperatingSystem*" property is more than
   enough.
2. I don't want a bidirectional relationship between the **Capture**
   and **OperatingSystem** types. Only a unidirectional relationship
   from **Capture** to **OperatingSystem** is needed.
3. I don't want to create a column in the database on the **Operating
   System** table named "*CaptureId*". I don't even know why that's
   required but I read an article somewhere suggesting to do it that
   way.
4. The SQL join generated should be an INNER JOIN and not an OUTER
   JOIN.
5. Do I really need to define the OperatingSystem property on the
   Capture type as virtual? I don't want this property to be lazy
   loaded.
6. Bonus point to someone that can explain this exception to me because
   I am completely lost. A Google search is hopeless for the Fluent API. I
   get a lot of hits if I am using the designer but I am thinking it is
   not related because all the results suggest to regenerate the model,
   which I don't think applies here.

**Update:**
I probably was not clear about this. I already have the database model set up in SQL Server. I am trying to understand how to configure an EF context using the Fluent API for an existing database model **without** using the designer. I understand that if I use the designer, I can simply ask it to generate my context from the database. That's not what I want. And for those that are curious why - Because I want to understand how to do it using the Fluent API.

**Update2:**
So, looks like with what I have set up, EF is generating joins correctly if in my query I specify a filter on a navigational property. Without doing that, no join is being generated in the query. Regardless, the navigational property is still not being populated!

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: Are you disabling conventions?

Comment: @Sidharth - No I am not. Which conventions do you suggest I disable?

Comment: You don't need to disable any conventions. See answer below

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So if you haven't used an ORM much like me and come from a background of using data mappers like MyBatis or something similar, the solution is this, given the example in my question.

First, you need can't declare your entity types as **sealed** and any properties that take part in associations need to be declared as **virtual**. This is because EF will extend the type at runtime with a dynamic proxy and also override your property with a dynamic proxy to enable lazy loading:

```
public class Capture {
    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Capture's Unique Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get and Set Capture's Operating System.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual OperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; set; }
}

public class OperatingSystem {
    /// <summary>
    /// Operating System's Unique Identifier.
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

If you don't do this, no error is thrown but EF will always set your associated properties as null.

Secondly, unless your associated property is not already configured for mapping, don't map it to a specific table because EF will complain that the same table is essentially mapped twice. In my example, I had already mapped the **OperatingSystem** type on its own and when setting up the association, I was mapping it again:

```
internal sealed class EntityCaptureConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Capture> {
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an Entity Capture Configuration.
    /// </summary>
    public EntityCaptureConfiguration() {
        this.ToTable("Capture");
        this.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        this.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("Id");

        this.HasRequired(m => m.OperatingSystem).WithRequiredDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("OperatingSystemId"));
    }
}
```

Finally, if you must absolutely declare your entity types as sealed and you don't want to declare any properties as virtual - you can't anyway on sealed types - in your context's configuration, disable proxies and lazy loading:

```
public sealed class EntityDefaultContext : DbContext {    
    /// <summary>
    /// Model Creating Event Handler.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        var entityCaptureConfiguration = new EntityCaptureConfiguration();
        var entityOperatingSystemConfiguration = new EntityOperatingSystemConfiguration();

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(entityOperatingSystemConfiguration);
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(entityCaptureConfiguration);

        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

That's all folks. I hope this helps someone like me in the future.